# How to create a (1280 x 720) bitmap on android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap

I'm trying to merge two bitmaps 640 pixel wide each, but the result is always a 1024 wide bitmap. How can i get android to create a 1280 wide bitmap?

I'm using the code below for scaling my bitmaps:

```
public static Bitmap scaleWidthImage(Bitmap image, int destWidth) {
    int origWidth = image.getWidth();
    int origHeight = image.getHeight();
    int destHeight;
    if (origWidth > destWidth) {
        destHeight = origHeight / (origWidth / destWidth);
    } else {
        destHeight = origHeight * (destWidth / origWidth);
    }
    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, destWidth, destHeight, false);
    return image;
}
```

And this code for mergin both bitmaps in one

```
fun mergeBitmap(fr: Bitmap, sc: Bitmap): Bitmap? {
    val comboBitmap: Bitmap
    val width: Int = fr.width + sc.width
    val height: Int = fr.height
    comboBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val comboImage = Canvas(comboBitmap)
    comboImage.drawBitmap(fr, 0f, 0f, null)
    comboImage.drawBitmap(sc, fr.width.toFloat(), 0f, null)
    return comboBitmap
}
```

When the widths of both bitmaps are less than 1024 pixels, the merged bitmap has the desired width, but when the sum of both is greater than 1024, it does not.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to merge two bitmaps (both have 640 as width and ?? as height) you want to merge them horizontally into one bitmap with 1280 as width and XX as height (where the XX is the max height of the two bitmaps) right ?

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI that's correct! I guess im not fully understading what does width and height bitmap properties mean on android studio. When using the debug tool to visualize my bitmap it seems to have another width and height, but it has the correct values on mWidth and mHeight Bitmap properties, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried with the two images below :

**Image 640x640 :**

[image]

**Image 640x800 :**

[image]

I've made this method to merge the two bitmaps into one:

```
 public static Bitmap drawBitmapsHorizontally(Bitmap bitmapOne, Bitmap bitmapTwo) {
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
        bitmaps.add(bitmapOne);
        bitmaps.add(bitmapTwo);
        int width = 0;
        for (Bitmap map : bitmaps)
            width += map.getWidth();

// you can set your favorite height (e.g. 720) instead of getting the max height of the two bitmaps.

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
                Math.max(bitmapOne.getHeight(),bitmapTwo.getHeight()),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM);
        bitmap.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOne, 0f, 0f, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTwo, bitmapOne.getWidth(), 0f, null);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Result **1280x800** :

[image]